# How can I do different results for scans from Barcode Scanner with three different buttons on Android with new IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, barcode

I have three buttons that onlongpress bring up my new IntentIntegrator scans via Barcode Scanner. I successfully have/had it scanning and using the code scanned to do something with when it is only one button.

How can I pass a value or something that when "protected void onActivityResult" is called it will know which button it came from so I can do different things with it depending on which button was long pressed.

My current setup is like this:

```
button1.setOnLongClickListener(this);
button2.setOnLongClickListener(this);
button3.setOnLongClickListener(this);}
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
    return true;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            IntentResult intentResult = 
               IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (intentResult != null) {

               String contents = intentResult.getContents();
               String format = intentResult.getFormatName();
               //do stuff with the scan. But I want to do different stuff depending on which button was pressed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

One, you can modify the IntentIntegrator source code so that it takes different REQUEST_CODES as constructor parameters (or just add a setRequestCode parameter).  Then in onActivityResult, check for which requestCode was returned (each of your buttons would return a different request code).  This would be the recommended approach.

Second option is the hacky one:  In your code, create a member variable that tracks which was the last button pressed (check whether the view passed in onLongClick matches button1,button2, or button3), and use that information in onActivityResult to choose what to do with the results passed back from barcode scanner.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but I sometimes forget the simple power of variables. Made an int and I change it depending on view and then read the int variable before I do stuff to the scan info.